# Hasura Real Time Function to update table

Tags: postgresql, hasura

am trying to figure out how to update this table, so when an order is placed, spots decrease by that order, and also free is updated. Then once a person checks out free will increment.

```
{
id: 1,
title: "Hotel 1",
price: 5,
rating: 4.2,
spots: 20,
free: 10,
coordinate: {
  latitude: 37.78735,
  longitude: -122.4334
},
description: `Description about this place`
```

}

Comment: Hmmm, that doesn't seem an ideal approach. You are not tracking the spots on a spot level? This should be some sort of aggregation query ideally, no?

Comment: @AbrahamLabkovsky yes am tracking the spots spot level, like each hotel has several spots. Do you have another approach you would suggest?

Comment: if you have a `spot` table, and some kind of a `available` or `checked_out` field, you would not need to update anything on the `hotel` table. Assuming your order flow changes the `spot` row status, you can make an aggregate subquery

Comment: let us know your part of your schema related to the question... and we'll find a way :)